# Popup showAtLocation is not working

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I'm using pop-window to show some text-view while clicking the edit-text . but pop-window is not showing at particular location ,it always showing at left top corner , here is my code ,what is wrong in that

```
    private void showPopup(Context context,final LinearLayout Parent) {


    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,MainActivity.parent,true);
    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
               layout,700,700);


    popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
    popupWindow.setHeight(500);


    new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER,300,150);
        }

    };


    }
```

Comment: Try setting GRAVITY.NO_GRAVITY instead and let me know if this works, since I can't test it anywhere atm

Answer (score 2):

Try Following Code:

```
public static Rect locateView(View v)
{
    int[] loc_int = new int[2];
    if (v == null) return null;
    try
    {
        v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
    } catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        //Happens when the view doesn't exist on screen anymore.
        return null;
    }
    Rect location = new Rect();
    location.left = loc_int[0];
    location.top = loc_int[1];
    location.right = location.left + v.getWidth();
    location.bottom = location.top + v.getHeight();
    return location;
}
```

And then use

```
popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, location.left, location.bottom);
```

Hope it helps...